# How to remove ChartLocation library in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to remove ChartLocation library in Javascript?

I was trying to import library for ChartLocation and unfortunately I couldn't find one for ChartLocation library. Apparently, this library was deprecated and there is no replacement yet. Please help on how to remove ChartLocation.

API::ChartLocation.
Affected type: ChartLocation.
ChartLocation is no longer available, and can be removed from your setup code.
Suggested fix: removal of ChartLocation

Comment: `JavaScript` != `Java`. Don't mis-tag your posts please :-). Anyway as per [ask] you're going to need to add a little bit more detail to make this clear.

Comment: No problem. You can [edit] the question when you're ready with a bit more context.